# what is the difference between .ipython vs .ipynb?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I know that .py is a regular python file. Also, .ipynb is a python notebook that contains the notebook code, and IPython is supposed to be an interactive shell for Python.

But when I want to write a Jupiter notebook code and run it in VSC, what extension should I use for my code file? .ipython or .ipynb?

Comment: I've never seen `.ipython` used as a file extension, always `.ipynb`.

Comment: I just wrote it by mistake but apparently, we can have this kind of file, and also I found an extension in VSC for these code files as well!

Comment: Then I got confused that what is the difference and what should I use and etc.

Comment: You may have a directory called `.ipython`.

Comment: I do not understand, could you give me more details?

Comment: So, just to make it clear to any reader, file extensions (on most systems) are merely *conventions*. You could use `.banana` if you wanted. But to follow the convention, I believe it *should* be `.ipynb`, I've never seen `.ipython` as an extension before

Comment: But I always thought that file extension is something more than you just explained. Because when you mentioned the extension of the file in VSC, all the keywords of the programming language become clear and meaningful.
Therefore, I guess there must be some special meaning for the files with the .ipython extension!

Comment: @Sarah It should be `.ipynb`. Python extension does not support `.ipython` file, and

Comment: What @juanpa.arrivillaga said is correct. It's just convention. And it's convention your VSC is set up to recognize. That's why you can get keywords highlighted when you use the typical extension.  For the sake of any IPython users who get here...If you are using scripts that contain IPython magics or use the exclamation point, the extension used by convention is `.ipy`, see [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/tutorial.html#startup-files). <to be continued..>

Comment: You can actually put most (close to all) code lines you run in notebook cells into lines of an `.ipy` file and run it with `%run <name>.ipy` from inside a notebook, or with`ipython <name>.ipy` on command line. That will let you use line magics or exclamation marks and can be helpful development. Note those IPython features actually make them run much slower than pure python implementations though, and so if it is something useful you may eventually want to convert to pure python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `.ipynb`. Python extension does not support `.ipython` file, and I could not find an extension that supports this file extension.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. However, if you want to look at the suggested extension for the .ipython file in VSC, this is the  Extension_ID:  "jithurjacob.nbpreviewer"

Comment: @Sarah When I want to execute this file, the VSCode will prompt: `Code language not supported or defined.`

Comment: Did you install the extension that I mentioned earlier?